# How to execute item updated event receiver only after workflow has finished execution?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, event-receivers

I have both, a Sharepoint 2010 Workflow and Event Receiver working on the item updated event in my Sharepoint 2013 List. Need to get the event receiver to work only after the workflow has finished execution or else the event receiver ends up sending null values to through the web service to another system.

Sharepoint environment being used here is Sharepoint 2013 on premises.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the workflow update a boolean field (E.g. "FireReceiver") on the list item when it is ready for the event receiver to fire. Then, add an if statement on your event receiver to only run your code when the boolean field value is true.

The event receiver will fire twice, but only run your code on the item updated event triggered by the workflow updating the boolean field to true.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case the event receiver is firing before the workflow. There is no guarantee if in the second time that it fires that the workflow would have completed. I need a fool proof method. If nothing works out will have to integrate the workflow and event receiver functionality.